# Where does Google pull the results for the define operator

Tags: google, google-search

Google has a define: operator which provides a list of definitions for a given word. Where does Google pull those definitions from? i.e. what does Google look for on a page to determine that that page is a definition for a word?

(This has been discussed a number of times on Webmaster World but nobody has come up with an answer yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Last August](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/08/google-dictionary-has-new-content.html), they switched to the Oxford Pocket Dictionary.

Seems odd nobody figured this out or at least got close.
Just use the define operator on a few words, eg [culture](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aculture&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a), [love](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=YUd&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=define%3Alove&aq=&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1), [robot](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=define%3Arobot&aq=&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1).
Then do exact phrase searches for the definitions: [culture](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+arts+and+other+manifestations+of+human+intellectual+achievement+regarded+collectively.%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a), [love](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22An+intense+feeling+of+deep+affection%3A+%22their+love+for+their+country%22.%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Wid&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=An+intense+feeling+of+deep+affection:+%22their+love+for+their+country%22.&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=44b3839bd44fe786), [robot](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22A+machine+capable+of+carrying+out+a+complex+series+of+actions+automatically.%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

In each case, the top result is at http://oxforddictionaries.com/ sometimes with slight variation since they probably use a different specific source dictionary of their own.

Answer (score 0):

It retrieves it from the most popular (linked and trusted) website on that topic which in many cases is wikipedia

Comment: Do you have any references to back this statement?